# Firebase Push Notifications Not Working IOS Production

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am able to get push notifications to fire in dev but not in production.  I have 2 separate projects in firebase- one for dev and one for prod.  I am using the same APN for both.

I have one key with the following selected:
Apple Push Notifications service (APNs)

I have uploaded the value to firebase under APNs Authentication Key.  The file itself is a p8 file. (most of stack overflows I see are p12)

I am automatically signing the app and always have been, wondering if that's my issue?  Do I need to manually upload it and if so how do I simply switch since I haven't signed it manually before.

Comment: p8 has to be enough from both prod and dev. You can try to send a push notification and debug using prod build configurations ()

Comment: I tried using debug prod build configs and don't see any logs when the event fires.  I have been trying with the 'Compose notification', what should I be looking for.  Again everything works in normal dev

Comment: not sure why, but the last time I just sent one it went through in prod debug.  Haven't touched code either.  Will try to release and see if it works this time

Comment: @StephenPhillips I am also facing the same issue, notification works fine for dev but not for prod,  how you resolved this issue.  my certificates are fine, but not sure why its not working using productions environment.